# Prove that for $f,g\in F[x]$, where $F$ is an infinite field, if $f(a)=g(a)$ for infinitely many elements $a\in F$, then $f=g$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

> Prove that for $f,g\in  F[x]$, where $F$ is an infinite field, if $f(a)=g(a)$ for infinitely many elements $a\in F$, then $f=g$.

I'm not entirely sure how to tackle the "infinitely many elements of a of field F" portion of this proof.  How would you even account for all those a's?

Comment: How many zeros can a nonzero polynomial have?

Comment: it would depend on the highest degree of the polynomial

Comment: Following Andres Caicedo, if a polynomial $f$ has degree $n$, what can you say on the number of zeros of $f$?

Comment: f would have n zeroes.

Comment: So what can you say about the zeros of the polynomial $f-g$?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the number of zeros of a **non-zero** polynomial is **less** then or equal to its degree.
This is a general theorem which is true for any polynomial over any field.
(Note that the number can indeed be  **less** then the degree, for example $p(x)=x^2+1$ has no zeros at all in $\mathbb{R})$.

Now, assuming the above result, reaching a contradiction is easy: assume $f(x)\neq g(x)$ are two different polynomials. Then their difference $f(x)- g(x)$ is a **non-zero** polynomial.

Hence, its number of roots is bounded by its degree and in particular, is finite: $\Rightarrow$ contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

The main fact is that if $a \in F$ is a zero of $f$, then we can write $f(x)=(x-a)q(x)$. This is a consequence of the division algorithm for polynomials because in general we have $f(x)=(x-a)q(x)+f(a)$.

This implies that if $f$ has $m$ zeros, then the degree of $f$ is at least $m$, unless $f=0$.

Apply this to $f-g$ and conclude that $f-g=0$ because it has infinitely many zeros.